# call Stripe API with await

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, stripe-payments

I'm trying to call the stripe API within an async method on the server (javascript, using MeteorJS) like so:

`selectedPlan = await Stripe.plans.retrieve(stripePlanId);`

the stripe API call (using the NodeJS library) has a callback to handle the error, but what syntax could I use to capture the error, if I'm using the await pattern?

tried something like

`[error, selectedPlan] = await Stripe.plans.retrieve(stripePlanId);`

but that did not work.

Comment: `retrieve` must return a promise, otherwise you cannot `await` it. If it takes a callback, promisify it first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
try {
  selectedPlan = await Stripe.plans.retrieve(stripePlanId);
} catch (error) {
  // error handling
}
```

Comment: i want the selectedPlan result available outside the try block though - as I need to merge it with other api call results. Simply declaring it outside the try block didn't seem to work; I would imagine the format of the response would be specific to the Stripe API as well, no?

Comment: Just declare `selectedPlan` outside of `try / catch` block. Like this: `let selectedPlan;`. And no, `await` is working like this — it resolves promise and throws an error in case it was rejected. Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Thanks - but my understanding is that the error captured via this method will only be if the actual API call itself fails - it won't get the detailed info if it fails for another (business logic) reason. i.e. the error caught in the catch() block is not the same 'error' in the callback function here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#retrieve_plan
is that wrong?

Comment: TL;DR: caught error will be the same as `error` from callback.Yes, it is wrong. Stripe API (nodeJS) is using Promises, so it always will work correctly. Actually, Stripe API could even not know about that, the work is done in `await` — it resolves the promise and returns its result, or throws error if the promise was rejected.